# Why does PhantomJS never render my canvases when I do a screen dump?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, phantomjs

I am trying to use PhantomJS to do a screendump of my Web based data viz app that uses Canvas for it's rendering.

Here is what I wrote:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('./index.html', function(status) {

    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load index.html');
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render('igv-screen-shot.png');
            phantom.exit();
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

When I run `index.html` in a browser I get this (notice the red border):
[image]

Everything within `div` with the red border - excluding the grey nav-bar with IGV at the left edge - is rendered on to a canvas. Here there are 3 canvas renders.

When I run the above screen dump code I get:
[image]

None of the canvases get rendered. Note, everything within the red `div` is created programmatically. The red `div` is the only element in `index.html` at launch. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add [page.onError](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html) callback to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Have you ever found a way around this issue? I'm getting a really odd bug with a batch of HTML pages, and all other pages I've built before never had a blank canvas issue when rendered to PNGs. Are there limitations to what PhantomJS can render with the canvas?

Comment: Doh! Well I feel dumb now, ends up the whole reason why my canvas wasn't showing up is because I had some Javascript function with "default" arguments written in the signature (I must of thought I was editing Typescript)... lost pretty much an entire day debugging this, it's too bad PhantomJS didn't pick up on that!